# boost::regex и pcre исключение Ran out of stack space trying to match the regular expression

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, boost, pcre

Когда то давно задавал подобный вопрос на другом форуме, но никто внятно не ответил.

Есть две библиотеки для работы с регулярными выражениями по стандарту PCRE.
Это boost::regex (или урезанный вариант std::regex) и библиотека PCRE.

Собственно есть сложное регулярное выражение.

там присутствуют подобные выражения

```
"+string_open+"(?>(?>(?!"+string_open+"|"+string_close+").)+|(?R))*"+string_close+"
```

Всё это дело замечательно отрабатывает для небольших входящих строк. но когда входящая строка превышает допустим 1000 символов и условия указанные в регулярном выражении выполняются, то выбрасывается исключение и в boost и в pcre.

Ran out of stack space trying to match the regular expression.

Собственно здесь говорится что происходит выход за пределы некоего стека.

1) Библиотеку pcre можно собрать из исходников, и увеличить там некоторые константы #define , точно не помню что именно там было, то ли указание на использование рекурсивной модели работы то ли еще что то.
Но в общем скомпилированная таким образом библиотека pcre стала работать с неограниченными по объему строками и решала поставленную задачу. Сейчас используется именно такая модель.

Однако данный метод увеличил время работы регулярных выражений в 10-20 раз. 
раньше программа поднималась за 4 секунды, а с использованием такого подхода 40-50 секунд.

2) В boost ни где не смог найти информацию, о том как и где изменять значения этого стека.

Что из себя представляет этот стек? Этот тип формируют сами библиотеки?

Невозможность изменить этот стек, выглядит нелогичным, потому что 
программа нормально отрабатывается для строки допустим 990 символов.
Время выполнения разбора 5 миллисекунд. Занимаемая память 400 кб.
Добавляются 20 символов и всё ran out stack.

Comment: Как дела с этой же регуляркой у [`PIRE`](https://github.com/dprokoptsev/pire)

Comment: А изменение размера стека командой bash не помогает?

    ulimit -s
    ulimit -s <new-value>

Comment: Вообще по поводу PIRE не помню, я её точно не испытывал.
Помню, что у yandex была собственная библиотека, наверное это она и есть. И там отсутствовали многие конструкции, вроде опережающих проверок (?<=) или (?=), которые удалили ради производительности. 
Смотрел разные реализации регулярных выражений для C++(их там более 10). Насколько помню только pcre и boost поддерживают полный стандарт PCRE.

У boost есть 
#define BOOST_REGEX_NON_RECURSIVE

#define BOOST_REGEX_BLOCKSIZE

#define BOOST_REGEX_MAX_CACHE_BLOCKS

в boost/regex/config.hpp

Но есть ли возможность без пересборки .lib сделать?

Comment: @alexlz 
это под win.

Comment: @manking Без пересборки нельзя, поскольку `BOOST_REGEX_NON_RECURSIVE` - это параметр конфига. Мне кажется, что пересборка с `BOOST_REGEX_NON_RECURSIVE` имеет неплохие шансы решить вашу проблему и это решение, естественно, будет лучше по сравнению с манипуляциями с размером стека (иначе всегда можно будет найти исходные данные, которые радостно свалят ваше приложение).

Comment: Мне казалось, что буст всегда пересобирается при подключении к проекту его хидеров, или нет?!

Comment: Может если сам boost собирать по другому? 

bjam release debug threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static install address-model=32 toolset=msvc stage

Но тогда время компиляции вырастет значительно.

Comment: @gecube, многие библиотеки из буста состоят не только из хедеров, но и из подключаемых библиотек.

Comment: - `boost::regex` - это не `template-only` библиотека, поэтому ее нужно билдить.

- Совсем, кстати забыл, можете попробовать `boost::xpressive`, которая `header-only`.

Comment: boost::xpressive пробовал и сейчас испытал. Она сыплет ошибки
mismatched parenthesis

Regex stack space exhausted

quantifier not expected

Еще почитал ответы на английском, там говорят что 

Xpressive makes extensive use of the stack because
its fast and cheap. If you want a regex library that uses very little
stack, use Boost.Regex in non-recursive mode.

То есть запустить Xpressive в non-recursive mode видимо не выйдет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Это](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/regex/doc/configuration.html) читали? Что бы сделал я?

1. Попробовал обе опции: и BOOST_REGEX_RECURSIVE, и  BOOST_REGEX_NON_RECURSIVE;
2. Увеличил бы BOOST_REGEX_BLOCKSIZE и BOOST_REGEX_MAX_BLOCKS.

Comment: Это я читал давно, но правда на русском сайте по boost.
И мне тогда казалось, что эти параметры надо указывать перед включением boost в свою программу.

Ладно попробую собрать заного. Спасибо.

Comment: Поставил  BOOST_REGEX_NON_RECURSIVE
Увеличил значения в 2 раза.
 define BOOST_REGEX_BLOCKSIZE 8096
 define BOOST_REGEX_MAX_BLOCKS 2096
Заработало. 
Увеличил входящий текст в два раза снова исключение.

Увеличил значения в несколько раз, скорость работы упала.

Отсюда еще вопрос.

Можно ли в boost самостоятельно указать требуемую .lib не влезая 
в файлы включения #include <boost\regex.hpp>.

Вот как то так

ifdef regex_128

pragma comment(lib, "libboost_regex_128.lib")

ifdef regex_256

pragma comment(lib, "libboost_regex_256.lib")


И насколько это нормально?

Comment: В любом случае, эти меры решают проблемы только на половину - на этапе сборки проекта, - а все же лучше не иметь ее в runtime. Думаю, можно найти способ динамический увеличивать размер блока при обнаружении больших входных данных, иначе не сегодня, так завтра проблема может всплыть снова, причем не у вас, а у пользователей вашей системы. Если boost этого не позволяет сделать, ищите другую реализацию RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

Для такой задачи лучше использовать более серьёзный парсер, нежели регулярные выражения. Например, [boost::spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html). Обе проблемы — стека и быстродействия — решаются сами собой. Из "недостатков" могу отметить большее время компиляции (порядка десятков секунд, частично решаемо с помошью прекомпилированных хэдеров) и достаточно крутая в начале кривая обучения (там активно используются ленивые вычисления, к логике которых надо привыкнуть — но дальше всё проще).

Comment: К недостаткам boost::spirit можно отнести и весьма нетривиальную отладку при возникновении ошибок анализа выражения, т.к. шаблонов там "тьма тьмущая".