# RegExp: удаление тега-обёртки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Имеется следующая структура:

```json
    <div различные атрибуты>
    <span атрибуты>текст</span>
    <span атрибуты>текст</span>
--> <div различные атрибуты>
    <ul атрибуты>
    <li атрибуты>текст</li>
    <li атрибуты>текст</li>
    <li атрибуты>текст</li>
    </ul>
--> </div>
    </div>
```

Нужно удалить внутренний `<div>` вокруг `<ul>` и `<li>`, при помощи регулярки. Этот внутренний `<div>` есть не всегда, но когда есть, его нужно удалить.

Поделитесь идеями, как это сделать с помощью регулярки?

Comment: В Вашем вопросе две большие ошибки. Во первых, у регулярных выражений есть много диалектов и пишут их на разных языках. А во вторых, парсить-модифицировать регулярками html - ещё то приключение. Возможно, выражение вида `<div.*</div>` в не жадном режиме и помогло бы, но не факт.

и напоследок. без указания конкретного языка программирования, писать об удалении сложновато.

Comment: язык - php. Хочу узнать такое регулярными выражениями вообще можно сделать?
К примеру, найти два подряд идущих </div></div> и заменить  на один еще можно. А когда есть <div> - все что угодно - внутренний <div>, даже не знаю, как поймать этот внутренний див и удалить.

Comment: В общем случае - нельзя. В каком то конкретном случае с конкретным html можно подобрать такой регексп, что все будет работать.

Почитайте [статью](http://xdan.ru/Uchimsya-parsit-saity-s-bibliotekoi-PHP-Simple-HTML-DOM-Parser.html) там описаны библиотеки для php для решения подобных задач.

Comment: Как можно быть не знакомым с [классикой][1]?
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

Регулярные выражения не подходят для универсального разбора HTML. 
html код подобен дереву, и имеет бесконечную вложенность, а регулярные выражения не рассчитаны на работу с деревьями или какими либо упорядоченными структурами(множествами).
Это уже [синтаксический разбор](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7) который пишется под конкретную задачу.

В случаи регулярных выражений такая возможность есть, но не во всех реализациях. И как правило при большом тексте, при использовании группирующих конструкций может происходить переполнение внутреннего стека памяти движка рег. выражений, то есть просто выбрасывается ошибка, или выполнение будет очень медленным.

Вот посмотрите пример:

[link text](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/155822/c-boost-regex-%D0%B8-pcre-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-ran-out-of-stack-space-trying-to-match-the-regular-expression)

То есть в принципе сделать это с помощью регулярных выражений можно, но не везде(не знаю про PHP), и это не надёжно.
Проще использовать специальные парсеры xml/html.
Почитайте [это](http://parsing-and-i.blogspot.ru/2009/08/html-php.html).

Answer (score 1):

Для конкретного случая, в PHP регулярное выражение и код будут такими:

```php
$re = '/<div[^>]*?>\s*(<ul[\s\S]*?<\/ul>)\s*<\/div>/mi';

$str = '<div различные атрибуты>
<span атрибуты>текст</span>
<span атрибуты>текст</span>
<div удаляемый блок>
<ul атрибуты>
<li атрибуты>текст</li>
<li атрибуты><div>блок внутри</div>текст</li>
<li атрибуты>текст</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>';

echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace($re, '$1', $str), ENT_QUOTES);
```

Рабочий пример на JS:

```js
let rExp = /<div[^>]*?>\s*(<ul[\s\S]*?<\/ul>)\s*<\/div>/gim;
let sHtml = `<div различные атрибуты>
<span атрибуты>текст</span>
<span атрибуты>текст</span>
<div удаляемый блок>
<ul атрибуты>
<li атрибуты>текст</li>
<li атрибуты><div>блок внутри</div>текст</li>
<li атрибуты>текст</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>`;
console.log(sHtml.replace(rExp, '$1'));
```